# Is it possible to have a progress bar without a loop?

Tags: python, loops, ffmpeg, progress-bar

I am using FFmpeg to do some video editing.  I would like to have a progress bar but there is not a loop in my code.  I've tried tqdm and putting my code in a loop with a range of 1 but that will only display the progress bar at 100%.  Maybe there is another way to accomplish this?  This is the code I'm using:

```
import subprocess

inmovie=mymovie.mp4
speed=str(4.0)
outmovie=newmovie.mp4
print('Converting file.......')
subprocess.call('ffmpeg -i '+inmovie+' -filter:v "setpts= '+speed+' *PTS" '+outmovie, shell=True)
print('Conversion done')
```

Comment: You need a `while` loop!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [pv](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) to monitor the progress of something through a pipe.

For example like this

`pv infile.mp4 | ffmpeg`

If you're to implement this into your code you can try something like

`subprocess.call('pv '+inmovie+' | ffmpeg -filter:v "setpts= '+speed+' *PTS" '+outmovie, shell=True)`